# React Native app crashes on the first launch only

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

When loading my app for the first time, it crashes with the following error:

`facebook::react::Recoverable: Could not open file/data/user/0/****/files/ReactNativeDevBundle.js: No such file or directory`

Upon reading similar issues, it points to a possible issue with my app version and the codePush SDK, however there seems to be no issues with the versioning of both.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? If i kill the app and reopen in the android emulator, the app works with no issues.

Comment: Similar to this issue. May be related to code push. https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1272